# "REmap" object in tabItem can't display

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, remap

I use the shinydashboard to develop Web application then meet a problem. As follows:

```
Server:
output$track_train <- renderREmap(
remapB(
center = BJU,
zoom = 9,
color = "grassgreen", 
markLineData   = markLine_data,
markPointData  = markPointData,
markLineTheme  = markLine_Control,
markPointTheme = markPointTheme,
geoData = gdata)) 

UI:
body <- dashboardBody(
tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = "wifi_01_company",
            tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
              tabPanel("trail",
                       icon = icon("tag"),
                       REmapOutput("track_train")
                        ),...

error message:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:156)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.min.js:2) htmlwidgets.js:475 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
at exports.OutputBinding.shinyBinding.find (htmlwidgets.js:475)
at a (init_shiny.js:15)
at f (init_shiny.js:215)
at initShiny (init_shiny.js:279)
```

If I comment "REmapOutput("track_train")" , everything is OK.

If I modify code: dashboardSidebar(disbale=TRUE), Simple to box(REmapOutput("track_train")), everythig is OK.

How can I output "REmap" object in tabItem? Please help me, thankes.

REmap is R package, the source code: https://github.com/Lchiffon/REmap

Comment: Could you post a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @SBista thank you for your reply. I put the example code on github, link:https://github.com/maliang1202/Learn/blob/master/shinydashboard

Comment: Seems to be some problem with `REmap`. Maybe post it as an [issue](https://github.com/Lchiffon/REmap/issues)?

Comment: @SBista OK，thank you.